# Fire ajax call on onclick and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to fire off an AJAX call based on the onclick event for a google map integration. The info_window_content function seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xw2y/ is the call to create the divs that reside within the map itself.

The "v" variable does in fact contain a store_id. So in the opening line of that function, it has the following:

```
var info_window_string = "<div class='maps_popup' id="+v.id+">";
```

Now I have an onclick event that I have duplicated and modified. The first onclick event works just fine and refreshes the panel as it should. The second onclick event doesn't work and the code for that is below:

```
 $("#div").click(function(){
   var store_id = $(this).find("div").attr("id");

    var pathname =  "ajax=1&store_id="+store_id+"&action=get_nearby_stores&distance="+distance+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&products="+$('#edit-products').val();

    $("#pocp_content").load("file1.php?" + pathname);

 });
```

That doesn't seem to work. I've also tried changing the div tag to be like this:

```
$("div").click(function(){
```

Which still doesn't work. As an added side hint. At one point I was able to get it to refresh but it was passing map-container as the store_id, instead of the id itself.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joke_Sense10,
but I think you're probably not binding the event to the right DOM element.

Try to open up the developer console in your browser (while being on the side you develop this code for), and enter `$("#div")` to see if the element it returns is the one you expect. You can also use `console.log($("#div"))` in the code for that.

answer in comments

Comment: awpeter - it seems when I do that I get a pretty deep list but when I seem to do $("div#map_canvas") it get a little closer. So does that help in figuring this out?

Comment: It would really help if i could see the html you're using this code with. If you can try posting it to jsfiddle.net or anywhere actually.

Comment: I did look at your site, and you have an `alert(store_id)` there right? And it doesn't work as well. The reason is the server is responding with an error. Look at your msg variable, just a little bit over that alert, it contains an error message and everything inside `if( results.success )` is never executed. It doesn't reach that point because `results.success` doesn't exist.

Comment: I would have to disagree with you. Reason being is that if you look at the list below and click on one of the items there, it works fine and nothing is changed. All I am trying to do is get the pins on the map to function the same way as the list

Comment: So how exactly should it function? If i click on the list i see a popup on the map (over the pin) with an address, website and logo. The same thing happens when i click on the list, what else should happen there?

Comment: What you want to look for is the + on the left hand side. When you click on an item in the list, open up the + on the left and you will see the details of that item clicked. As you click, the + will close again and if you open it again you will see the new item there. That is how I would like to try to get the push pins to work as well

Comment: Can you find `google.maps.event.addListener(marker...` and just below that is `infowindow.open(map,marker);` if you add your code right below that line it will work when you click on a marker, so you can add the code you need there. If you add the same code as you use in the list it will probably work.

Comment: Also you can at least upvote this answer so other people see your problem in more detail and maybe can help you as well.

Comment: GENIUS! So now it works like a charm. I just had to use var store_id = v.id (which is gotten from the msg values) and then paste the rest of the code there and it viola! It works! Thanks so much awpeter. You definitely helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

For a larger number of elements, always use .on() method as the latter will bind an single event listener on one of the topmost nodes in the DOM tree.

```
$(document).on("click","#"+v.id, function(){
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work either. $(document).on("click","#"+v.id, function(){ var store_id = $(this).find("div").attr("id"); Where am I going wrong?